# partial view display with targeted div in MVC3 Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My Controller Action is:

```
        public ActionResult PVInPage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ViewPage2()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

My Main View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewPage2", "PartialViewInPage"))
{    
    <input type="submit" value="Call Page Two" />  
}

<div id="DisplayPartilView">

        @*display partial view *@

</div>
```

My Partial view Is :

```
  @{
        ViewBag.Title = "View Page 2";
    }

    <div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:Gray" >


     <h1> This is my Partial view </h1>

    </div>
```

Now I want to do : when i click submit button in my main view then my partial view arise in

My main view inner div with id="DisplayPartilView". 
Thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load data/html into a page without navigating to a different page you need to use Ajax.

ASP.Net MVC provides a set of helpers to work with Ajax (they are all use [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under the hood so you can always drop back to one level and write your ajax calls by hand).

But in your case the `Ajax.BeginForm` provides everything what you need:

So change your main view to:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ViewPage2", "PartialViewInPage", 
        new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "DisplayPartilView" }))
{    
    <input type="submit" value="Call Page Two" />  
}

<div id="DisplayPartilView">

        @*display partial view *@

</div>
```

And to make it work you need to reference the following script in your main view or in your layout file after jQuery:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewPage2", "PartialViewInPage"))
```

will refresh page, that's why you need `ajax`

[.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get data from all inputs and [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make `post` request, then set partial:

```
$('#DisplayPartilView').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project i am doing like this it's below

this is my button which is i click then my partial view load in my div like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnLode").click(function () {
            $("#LodeForm").load("/City/ShowAllState", function () {
                alert("Your page loaded Successfully !!!!!!!");
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="LodeForm">
</div>
```

and this is another solution for this problem

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchCountry", "City",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "Get",
        LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
        UpdateTargetId = "CountryListID",
    }))
{

    <input type="submit" value="search Country" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("SearchCountry", "City")" />        
}
<div id="CountryListID">
</div>
```

i think this will help you